# Как перенести настройки материала модели сделанной в Blender в Unity?

Tags: unity3d, model, blender

Делаем импорт моделей из Blender в Unity, и они переносятся без своей окраски и настроек. Материал перенесся, а его цвет и настройки - нет. Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1):

- Нужно извлечь текстуры и материалы вашей модели.

  1 Выбрать вашу модель в окне Project

  2. В окне Inspector перейти на вкладку Materials
  3. Создать папку и извлечь в нее текстуры вашей модели (Extract Textures)
  4. То же самое проделать с материалами модели (Extract Materials)
  5. Выбрать вашу модель в окне сцены и раскрыть его на компоненты
  6. Выбираем каждый компонет модели и в окне Inspector в разделе Shaders изменяем параметр с "Standart" на "Legasy Shaders/Deffuse
     Detail"
  7. Наслаждаемся результатом.

[Источник ответа](https://youtu.be/m3ufW7Q3Tr8)